# Retry jobs until first fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking for plugin or any advice how to write script which will retry success jobs unitl first fail.

The point is, that I have found only opposite plugins(eg. Build Flow Plugin), which allows to retry until first success.

Comment: So it runs jobs over and over until first failure. And then what? Never run anything agian? Email?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Conditional build step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin%20Conditional%20Build%20Step%20Plugin).
You will want to add a conditional step(single) and then make it "Trigger/call builds on other projects" for the same project with a condition "Current build status" -> success. This will force the project to enter an endless loop until it fails. You can add a build step on "Failed" if you want to do something else then.